# JPA join query with not in condition

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I'm having three tables Client, Task and TaskClient.
TaskClient is having client as foreign key.
Below is the bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TaskClient")
public class TaskClient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client", unique=false)
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="task", unique=false)
    private Task task;
}
```

Below is TaskClientDAO:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskCliebtDAO extends JpaRepository<TaskClient, Serializable> {

    @Query("")
    public List<ClientBean> findClientAvailableForTask(Integer taskId);
}
```

Here I want to search all clients which are not associated with given template id.

For Example:

```
Client                  Task                 TaskClient
=========              ======              ===================
id     name          id     name          id      client     task
-----  ------       -----  -----         -----   --------   ------
1       c1            1     t1             1         1         1      
2       c2            2     t2             
3       c3
```

As above, I'm having 3 clients c1, c2 and c3. Same way I'm having 2 tasks t1 and t2. 
Now TaskClient is holding mapping of Task and Client. In example client id 1 is associated with task id 1.
Now I want a query where i will give taskid and in return I want all available clients which are not associated with given task id in TaskClient table.
If I give task Id as 1, then i should get c2 and c3.
If i give task Id as 2, then i should get c1, c2, and c3.

Note: Client and Task bean doesn't have any reference to TaskClient bean

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Start by writing a query used to select the IDs of the the clients linked to the given task. Then use that query as a subquery to find all the clients whose ID is not in this set of IDs.

Comment: I tried "select c from Client inner join TaskClient t where t.client.id != c.id and t.task.id = :taskId"  in clientDAO. It returned me TaskClient not mapped.

Comment: I also tried "select c from  client c where c.id not in (select t.client.id from TaskClient t where t.task.id = :taskId)". Got same "Not mapped" exception

Comment: The second query looks correct. Post it in your question, and post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...actually second query worked. There was issue with the case of TaskClient. In my codebase its Taskclient and I used it as TaskClient. Thats the reason it was failing. Now after changing it to Taskclient, its working. Thanks for you suggestion :)